# Is there a LEFT function in kql?

Tags: kql

In SQL, in order to grab *n* characters from the left side of a string, you can use the LEFT function:

```sql
SELECT LEFT('Hello World', 5)
-- "Hello"
```

There doesn't appear to be a left or right function in the docs on [scalar functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalarfunctions):

[image: Scalar Functions]

**Q**: How do you do select left most characters in KQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction) function:

```cs
substring(source, startingIndex [, length])
```

#### LEFT

**SQL**: `SELECT LEFT('Hello World', 5)`
**KQL**: `print substring("Hello World", 0, 5)`

#### RIGHT

**SQL**: `SELECT RIGHT('Hello World', 5)`
**KQL**: `print substring("Hello World", -5, 5)`